# Hyphenating measurements in case of a fraction

Tags: hyphenation, measuring-units, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

I am now quite comfortable with the rules of hyphenating measurements (For example, 5-foot-long rod, 7-inch-long handle, etc.) However, what is the rule for hyphenation if the number is a fraction. Say, 1/2-inch-long piece of ginger? I would ideally want to keep the fraction, the instance I am using it in, does not allow the usage of "half-inch-long".

Comment: i don't see any problem with 1/2-inch-long piece

Comment: I would avoid the construction. "The rod's length is 5 feet." Or "the rod is 5 feet in length."  Or various other constructions, depending on context. I would not use "foot-long" as a unit, because it's not. A "foot-long" is a hot dog.

Comment: @puppetsock Or in the U.S., a 12-inch sub from Subway.

Answer (score -1):

You can use both variants.

Here's an [example](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/animals/invertebrates/group/stick-insects/) :

"Size

Stick insect species, often called walking sticks, range in size from the tiny, ***half-inch-long*** Timema cristinae of North America, to the formidable 13-inch-long Phobaeticus kirbyi of Borneo."

Comment: So would you say that 1/2-inch-long would be incorrect usage?

Comment: It's OK as well. For example: https://www.gliderite.com/260909-1-1-2-square-glass-white-cabinet-knob/

Comment: The gliderite link is broken. As the question is specifically about using the numerical version of the fraction – i.e. "1/2" instead of "half" – I recommend you *[edit] your post* (rather than adding a comment) to provide an example of the **numerical** hyphenation. NB I don't think a product description on a hardware store's webpage is reliable as "correct usage".